# Should I flag comments about lacking of reference if they are obsoleted, for the sake of future visitors?

Tags: discussion, moderation, deleted-comments, flagging

For example, [this strongly-encourage-references comment](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/1108/can-neem-leaves-be-taken-directly-azadirachta-indica-nimtree#comment2252_1124) is obsoleted after the references have been added.

Should I flag them (and delete them if I can)? They are obsoleted, obviously. But since in Health, it is strongly encourage to have references in answers, so I think leave them there as notes for future visitors is also a good idea.

What do you think?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you noted, the comment is no longer relevant after references have been added. This is the archetype of obsolete. Please do flag as such. And thank you!

We do strongly encourage references, and Meta etc. are available to explicate that for anyone who wonders. There are also many still-applicable comments to that effect. There’s no need to have obsolete comments lying around as a testimony.

<sub><s>Note: I am leaving linked obsolete comment for the time being to avoid obsoleting this Meta discussion.  :-)</s></sub>